# Select rows from a dataframe using another dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. First one has 2 columns - a) Full Name b) Phone Number
Second has 1 column - Name
What I am trying to achieve is that the names present in the second dataframe to be matched with names present in first dataframe - Only the names which are present in both the dataframes to be saved along with the phone number in first dataframe in another dataframe.

Basically what I have been able to achieve is compare two files with different names and get common names amongst them. The first file has phone numbers while the second one doesn't. What I want to achieve is to add the phone numbers to the matched names.

```
df3=df1.loc[df1["Full Name"].isin(df2["Name"])]
Error - get_loc return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
```

This is what I have tried but I am getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an inner merge by [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), as follows:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='Full Name', right_on='Name')
```

Comment: Getting a key error for some reason. I tried implementing merge before but keep on getting key error.

Comment: @PrakharSood  Can you post some sample data to the question?  Maybe the  first few rows by e.g.  `df1.head(5)`  for each dataframe